# Validate combobox with jquery easyui

Tags: jquery, validation, combobox, jquery-validate, jquery-easyui

In my page, has two plugins: [jquery validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) and [jquery easyui](http://www.jeasyui.com/index.php) ..
I use jQuery Validate to validate the datas inputs in a form..
And I use jQuery EasyUI to customize a combobox, allowing to search datas in combobox.

So, I put the Validate plugin:

```
$("#form1").validate({
        rules:{
            filename:{
                required: true,
                minlength: 3
            },
            leia:{
                required: true
            }
        }
    });
```

That's ok! Is's work!
But when I put the easyUI plugin, and set class in combobox 'leia' the validation of 'leia' didn't work more.

```
<form id="form1" action="" method="post">
        <div>
                <label>Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="filename" />
        </div>
        <div>
                <label>Leiame:</label>
                <select name="leia" class="easyui-combobox">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="1">Java</option>
                        <option value="2">C</option>
                        <option value="3">C#</option>
                        <option value="4">PHP</option>
                </select>
    </div>

        <input id="submit-go" type="submit" name="add" value="Add" />
</form>
```

When I take off the class in 'leia', the validation works!
Can anybody help me ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: why don't you use validation of easyui itself rather than using other validation plugins.. see validatebox documentation...

Comment: ok! I'm trying to do this! Thanks!

Comment: I cannot use validatebox, because the jquery validate is better, offer more resources ... So, I want to use jquery validate and jquery easyui ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is allow jQuery Validate to execute on hidden elements.  EasyUI is simply hiding the select and replacing it with its own elements, but ultimately updating your select behind the scenes.  In order to make this work:

```
$("#form").validate({
    ignore:'',//by default it ignores hidden inputs, so setting this to blank overrides that
    rules: {              
        leia: {
          required: true
        }
      },
      errorPlacement: function(error,element){
        if (element.hasClass('combo-value')){
            element.closest("span.combo").after(error);
        } else {
            element.after(error);   
    }   }       
});
```

I've added the errorPlacement function as well, which moves the error message outside of the easy UI markup (otherwise it gets buried in a span with `overflow:hidden` set).

See it working here:  http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/B5XX7/2/

Comment: thanks Ryley! Very good! But don't show the error message of 'leia' input.. See: $("#form").validate({
  ignore:'',
  rules:{
   leia:{
    required: true
   }
  },
  // Error messages
  messages:{
   leia:{
    required: "Please, select a item"
   }
  }
 });

Comment: The message error is showing when occurred a error in 'leia' input ... But in other inputs, the error message don't show.. See: $("#form").validate({
  ignore:'',
  rules:{
   filename:{
    required: true,
    minlength: 3
   },
   leia:{
    required: true
   }
  },
  messages:{
   filename:{
    required: "Required",
    minlength: "Enter at least 3 characters"
   },
   leia:{
    required: "Please, select a item"
   }
  },
  errorPlacement: function(error,element){
   element.closest("span.combo").after(error);
  }
 });

Comment: As you see, in 'filename' input, the error message don't show ... Only in 'leia' input the error message is showing

Comment: I see.  You should look up how `errorPlacement` works.  I have edited it to fix this problem, but you should really try to understand it as well.